# Windows Update "cannot connect", and Windows store cannot download apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-store

So, I have been having issues with Windows 10 Update and Windows Store.

To start, This PC is running Windows 10 Home, which was updated from Windows 8.1.

I don't exactly know when the issues began (I don't often use the windows store, and all updates *should* be running automatically after hours). However, now when attempting to download a new app, I ran into problems.

Firstly, the error I received when attempting to download an app was this:

> Something unexpected happened
>
> Code: 0x80072F8F

I then attempted to "Get Updates" (from the store) to the same effect. I then tried running Windows Update, which gave me a separate issue:

> We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet.

I then went exploring for some solutions: I found a [Microsoft Answers article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/error-code-0x80072f8f/d5006dbe-5946-4d68-8f08-8620eeb65efd?auth=1) on the Error Code, as well as [another Microsoft Answers article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_store/how-to-repair-the-new-store-beta-in-windows-10/d904b96d-731f-42d5-b858-161105381279?tm=1424456609665) about fixing the windows Store, and a [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e7a0d575-6d0b-49f5-b6c7-9c9637ee9e6b/windows-update-we-couldn39t-connect-to-the-update-service-well-try-again-later-or-you-can?forum=win10itprogeneral).

None of these articles have been able to help me fix the issues. In the TechNet article it advised collecting a log of the Update Service, which I have (but is apparently too big to upload - let me know what information I can take from it and post what is relevant).

I also have the Sophos Firewall Hardware, and Sophos Endpoint Antivirus running in the network.

Comment: Is your computer part of a domain and is a WSUS server running on it? Or did you try some custom windows update patch management software? Also, have you tried again after disabling/bypassing the firewall(s)?

Comment: 0x80072F8F = ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE, ERROR_INTERNET_DECODING_FAILED. disable sophos and look what happens

Answer (score 1):

Turn off all of your Firewall and antivirus temporarily.

Run this official Windows Update troubleshooter:

Windows Update Troubleshooter

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4027322/windows-windows-update-troubleshooter

Then download the Windows Update again.